# Python - Check if strings/initials in a list are present in another list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to check if the names or initials in one list are present in another list.

I have 2 lists like:

```
l1 = ["JACK", "JOHN", "A", "PAUL", "STEVE"]
l2 = ["J", "ANN", "JACK", "STEVEN", "P"]
```

In the above list "JACK" and "JOHN" from l1 both match with the initial "J" in l2 and "JACK" from l1 matches with "JACK" in l2. Also "A" from l1 matches with "ANN" in l2. Similarly with "PAUL" and "P", but "STEVE" and "STEVEN" don't match. So the result should be "Not full match".

But if l1 didn't have "STEVE" and be like:

```
l1 = ["JACK", "JOHN", "A", "PAUL"]
```

As "STEVE" or "S" both don't doesn't exist in l2 and all other items match the result should be "Full match".

So I must have all items in l1 as either fully present or as initials in l2, but having all items from l2 in l1 isn't necessary.

I tried code from other similar questions but none of them gets the exact result. They output a positive result as they either match only initials of all items or match even "STEVE" with "STEVEN" which i don't want.

I suppose this can be done by a conditional statement that checks all items in either list having a length of 1 with the first index of all items in the other list(so that any initial in either list gets matched with all full names); and full strings from only l1 with full strings in l2(so that full names from only l1 are matched with full names in l2)

Please be a little elaborative as i'm just a beginner learning python as my first programming language.

EDIT: As asked by Devesh I'm pasting below all the code I tried.

```
for elem in l2 or elem in l1:
    if (len(elem)) == 1:
        print('yes')
        if any(elem[0] for elem in l1) == any(elem[0] for elem in l2):
            print("yes")
```

```
for elem in l1 or elem in l2:
    if l1[elem][0]  == l2[elem][0]:
        print("yes")
```

```
for elem in l1:
    if len(elem) == 1:
        print([elem for elem in l1 if any(elem in x for x in l2)])
        print([elem for elem in l2 if any(elem in x for x in l1)])
```

```
for b in l2:
  for a in l1:
    if a in b or b in a:
      present.add(b)
      break
    else:
      notPresent.add(b)

print(present)
print(notPresent)
```

Comment: Did you try anything to solve it? You need to show effort before we can help you

Comment: I don't think it would mean anything Devesh, but as you asked I'll edit the question and paste all the different code I tried.

Comment: "So I must have all items in l1 as either fully present or as initials in l2, but having all items from l2 in l1 isn't necessary."  So why 'A' in L1 matches 'ANN' in L2?  Not clear.

Comment: Excuse me for not being totally clear. The logic is that 'A' is initial for 'ANN' so I need it to be matched too.

Comment: Because I'm not 100% sure of the rules, does this work for you? `print(all([x[0] in l2 or x in l2 for x in l1 if len(x) > 1] + [x in [x[0] for x in l2] for x in l1 if len(x) == 1]) and 'Full match' or 'Not full match')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the list(l1) and check if the element is present in the l2, if not check is the first character present. If not you can simply return.

```
l1 = ["JACK", "JOHN", "A", "PAUL", "STEVEN"]
l2 = ["J", "ANN", "JACK", "STEVEN", "P"]


def compare(l1, l2):
    for i in l1:
        if not (i in l2 or i[0] in l2):
            if len(i) == 1:
                is_matched = False
                for j in l2:
                    if ( j[0] == i):
                        is_matched = True
                if not is_matched:
                    return "not matched"
            else:
                return "not matched"
    return "matched"

print compare(l1, l2)
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first also but this doesn't match 'A' with 'ANN' when it should.

Comment: I have modified the code for achieving that condition(A matched with ANN)

Comment: Hi Kuldeep. Thanks for this. This works perfectly. I'm a noob and i don't actually understand how this worked. Could you please briefly explain how it works.

Comment: You just need iterate over the first list if it present in second list then its matched otherwise you need check if the length of the element , if it is one then you need check whether any element in the second list which starts from that.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I just wrote on the go. Check if it works for you. This code can be simplified further but that is a job for you ;)

```
l1 = ["JACK", "JOHN", "A", "PAUL", "STEVE"]
l2 = ["J", "ANN", "JACK", "STEVEN", "P"]
i = 0
length1 = len(l1)
length2 = len(l2)
for first in l1:
    count = 0
    for second in l2:
        count += 1
        if len(second) == 1:
            if first[0] == second:
                break
        elif len(first) == 1:
            if first == second[0]:
                break
        else:
            if first == second:
                break
        if count == length2:
            i = 1
if i == 1:
    print("Not Match")
else:
    print("Match")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this is how you can try it:

1. Create 2 lists from l2, 1 with only initials to check for l1 where
   length is greater than 1.
2. Other list with initials from l2 to check items having length=1 in l1.

Code:

```
l1 = ["JACK", "JOHN", "A", "PAUL", "STEVE"]
l2 = ["J", "ANN", "JACK", "STEVEN", "P"]
one_letter = [x for x in l2 if len(x)==1]
first_letter = [x[0] for x in l2 if len(x)>1]

l3=[]
for x in l1:
    if len(x)>1:
        if x[0] in one_letter:
            l3.append(x)
    else:
        if x in first_letter or x in l2:
            l3.append(x)

print(l3)
```

Shorter Version:

```
l4 = [x if x[0] in one_letter else x if x in first_letter or x in l2 else '' for x in l1]
l4.remove('')
```

Output:

```
['JACK', 'JOHN', 'A', 'PAUL']
```